# Custom settings.json file into UnitTests

Tags: c#

How can I load a custom file into a UnitTest?
Trying to specify the path returns a "...was not found and is not optional" error.

Code:

```
public class OptionsTests
{

    public IConfiguration _config;
    public IConfiguration InitConfiguration()
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("...\\TestProject\\Options\test.settings.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
        return config;
    }

    public OptionsTests()
    {
        _config = InitConfiguration();


    }

    [Fact]
    public void Should_GetCorrectSettings()
    {
        var options = _config.Get<MyClass>();
    }
```

Any ideas?
I've tried specifying the absolut path to the file.
I've also made sure to copy it to the output folder so it moves when compiled.

Answer (score 0):

After trying around for a good while -
I found that the Debug output for Tests is

```
... /bin/Debug/net 6.0  (project dependable) /
```

so the solution was adding the path in the expected relative output form.
`./TestProject/Options/test.settings.json` in my case.

Comment: Not quite. A far better solution is to change the file's Copy action to `Copy Always` and use a relative path. `./` is relative to the *runner*, which, if you use any IDE, will run inside `bin/Debug/net6.0`.